# Installing Ubuntu 16.04 in my laptop

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, 16.04

I have seen some posts related to installation of ubuntu 16.04 but couldn't figure out anything. Let me make few honest statements. In the first place I dont even know how to install an operating system. Secondly I see that to install ubuntu I have to first download it. I do not know which all files to download. It is my earnest request if someone can give step by step details right from downloading to installing in minutest details.

I have a Dell Inspiron system
Windows 10 installed
4 GB RAM
500 GB Hard Disk
Processor- Intel

Comment: you want dual boot or you want to erase disk and inastall ubuntu only

Comment: I want ubuntu 16.04 along side Windows 10

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For dual boot follow these steps to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10
(taken from https://verdictforu.com/2016/09/06/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-16-04-and-windows-10/)

> **Step 1: Prepare Windows Machine for Dual-Boot**
>
> 1. The first thing you need to take care is to create a free space on the computer hard disk in case the system is installed on a single
>    partition.
>
>    Login to your Windows machine with an administrative account and
>    right click on the
>
>    > Start Menu -> Command Prompt (Admin)
>
>    in order to enter Windows Command Line.
>
>    [image]
> 2. Once in CLI, type diskmgmt.msc on prompt and the Disk Management utility should open. From here, right click on C:(or whichever
>    partition you want) partition and select Shrink Volume in order to
>    resize the partition.
>
>    C:\Windows\system32>diskmgmt.msc
>
>    [image]
> 3. On Shrink C:(or your selected partition) enter a value on space to shrink in MB (use at least 20000 MB depending on the your partition
>    size) and hit Shrink to start partition resize as illustrated below
>    (the value of space shrink from below image is lower and only used for
>    demonstration purposes).
>
>    Once the space has been resized you will see a new unallocated
>    space on the hard drive. Leave it as default and reboot the computer
>    in order to proceed with Ubuntu 16.04 installation.
>
>    [image]
>
>    [image]
>
> **Step 2: Install Ubuntu 16.04 with Windows Dual-Boot**
>
> 1. Download Ubuntu 16.04 LTS ISO file.
>
>    Download ISO file of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS from their official
>    [website](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)
>
>    Once the ISO file is downloaded, burn it into a USB pendrive or DVD
>    and Boot your system with bootable USB Pen drive or DVD.
> 2. Select ‘Install Ubuntu’ to start installation.
>
>    [image]
>
>    [image]
> 3. Preparing to Install Ubuntu 16.06 LTS
>
>    In case your system is connected to the Internet and wants to
>    install third party tools during installation, you can select both the
>    options as shown in below snap otherwise leave the options uncheck.
>
>    [image]
> 4. Now it’s time to select an Installation Type. You can choose to Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager, option that will
>    automatically take care of all the partition steps.
>
>    Use this option if you don’t require personalized partition scheme.
>    In case you want a custom partition layout, check the Something else
>    option and hit on Continue button to proceed further.
>
>    The option Erase disk and install Ubuntu should be avoided on
>    dual-boot because is potentially dangerous and will wipe out your
>    disk.
>
>    [image]
> 5. On this step we’ll create our custom partition layout for Ubuntu 16.04. On this guide will recommend that you create two partitions, one for `root` and the other for `home` accounts data and no partition
>    for `swap` (use a `swap` partition only if you have limited RAM
>    resources or you use a fast SSD).
>
>    To create the first partition, the `root` partition, select the
>    free space (the shrink space from Windows created earlier) and hit on
>    the `+` icon below. On partition settings use the following
>    configurations and hit OK to apply changes:
>
>    - Size = at least 20000 MB
>    - Type for the new partition = Primary
>    - Location for the new partition = Beginning
>    - Use as = EXT4 journaling file system
>    - Mount point = /
>
>    [image]
>
>    [image]
>
>    Create the home partition using the same steps as above. Use all
>    the available free space left for home partition size. The partition
>    settings should look like this:
>
>    - Size = all remaining free space
>    - Type for the new partition = Primary
>    - Location for the new partition = Beginning
>    - Use as = EXT4 journaling file system
>    - Mount point = /home
>
>    [image]
>
>    Create a Swap partition and give a size to swap, mostly it is
>    double of your ram size. so if ram is 2 gb swap should be 4 gb.
>
>    [image]
> 6. If you **don't want to create a swap partition** than hit the Install Now button in order to apply changes to disk and start the
>    installation process.
>
>    A pop-up window should appear to inform you about swap space.
>    Ignore the alert by pressing on Continue button.
>
>    Next a new pop-up window will ask you if you agree with committing
>    changes to disk. Hit Continue to write changes to disk and the
>    installation process will now start.
>
>    [image]
> 7. On the next screen adjust your machine physical location by selecting a city nearby from the map. When done hit Continue to move
>    ahead.
>
>    [image]
> 8. Next, select your keyboard layout and click on Continue button.
> 9. Pick up a username and password for your administrative sudo account, enter a descriptive name for your computer and hit Continue
>    to finalize the installation.
>
>    This are all the settings required for customizing Ubuntu 16.04
>    installation. From here on the installation process will run
>    automatically until it reaches the end.
>
>    [image]
>
>    [image]
> 10. After the installation process reaches its end hit on Restart Now button in order to complete the installation.
>
>     The machine will reboot into the Grub menu, where for ten seconds, you will be presented to choose what OS you wish to use further:
>     Ubuntu 16.04 or Microsoft Windows.
>
>     Ubuntu is designated as default OS to boot from. Thus, just press Enter key or wait for those 10 seconds timeout to drain.
>
>     [image]
>
>     [image]
> 11. After Ubuntu finishes loading, login with the credentials created during the installation process and enjoy it. Ubuntu 16.04 provides
>     NTFS file system support automatically so you can access the files
>     from Windows partitions just by clicking on the Windows volume.
>
>     [image]
>
>     [image]
>
> That’s it! In case you need to switch back to Windows, just reboot the
> computer and select Windows from the Grub menu.
>
> Images are taken from - [Tecmint](http://www.tecmint.com/) and [Linuxtechi](http://www.linuxtechi.com/)
>
> Hope it helps you to dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 10.

Comment: I think you're making this overly complicated - there's no need to manually create free space using Windows disk management, and there's no need to manually allocate partitions during the install either. Ubuntu installer does the exact same thing for you if you select "Install alongside Windows" at step 4, no manual tinkering with partitions required. Letting the installer do these things itself is _a lot easier_ for noobs :-)

Comment: As far as I go, never trust automatic partitioning options in Ubuntu installers, as you may end up with nasty surprises. When installing Ubuntu, personally I always prepare the partitions manually. Since he wants to keep a dual-boot set-up, most flexible would be to create a new extended partition and inside it create the several logical partitions.

Comment: @JonasCz yes, but that's just because the OP is blindly stealing content from other sources so he repeated everything.

Answer (score 1):

If your laptop has a dvd reader go to the Ubuntu website and download Ubuntu 16.04 desktop and burn the iso to a dvd.  If you use the subject laptop to download, Ubuntu will select the correct architecture (32 or 64 bit).  If you use another machine and you don't know the laptop architecture, select 32 bit.  Then boot your laptop from the dvd (enter the laptop BIOS and set the boot priority to CD/DVD reader if needed).  Explore the option to test Ubuntu without installing to check hardware compatibility.  If you like, then select the install option from the Ubuntu desktop.

[how to install Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop)

Answer (score 0):

It's not too difficult. First, you need to download Ubuntu. To do that, go to the [download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) on the website, click the "Download" button, and then click the "Take me to the the download" link at the bottom of the page (unless you want to donate..). The download will start automatically.

Once you've downloaded the ISO file, you need to decide weather to install from a DVD or from a USB stick. If you want to to use a DVD, you will need need a blank DVD. If you want to use a USB stck (flash drive), you'll need a flash drive (obviously..). If you're using a DVD, [read the burning a DVD guide](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows). If you're using a flash drive, read the [Creating a bootable USB stick on windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows), and follow the instructions there to put the ISO file on the USB stick or burn a DVD.

Then, restart your computer, with the USB stick connected, or the DVD in the drive, and follow the installation instructions (which are pretty simple). It will also give you options weather to install Ubuntu alongside windows, or to replace Windows entirely. See [the installation guide for details](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop).

Let me know if you get stuck somewhere, and I'll try to help.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to also consider using VirtualBox to install it inside windows, Any errors you make learning Ubuntu will be MUCH less likely to hurt your windows install. When you have more confidence, you can go ahead with a dual boot install.